# Semantic proofs to syntactic proofs

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

Given a first-order logic theory $T$ and and a formula $F$, suppose I have semantically proved that $T\vdash F$. That is, I have proved that any model $M$ of $T$ satisfies $F$ and I conclude by [Gödel's completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem).

Do I have a general algorithm to extract from the above a syntactic proof of $T\vdash F$, i.e. a finite sequence of formulas that respects inference rules, uses $T$ and finishes at $F$ ?

If no such algorithm exists, then did I really prove $T\vdash F$ ? The completeness theorem was just an example of how to indirectly prove that there exists a proof of $T\vdash F$, without explicitly giving this latter proof. What if my indirect proof uses an inaccessible cardinal, do I have to mention the awkward
$$ (\text{ZFC + Inaccessible cardinal})\; \vdash\; (T \vdash F) $$
And then this proof can also be indirect, so I might continue stacking theories to the left and it becomes a nightmare. Don't semantic or other indirect formal proofs somewhat defeat the purpose of formal logic, that we should be absolutely certain that the formal proofs exist and are correct?

Comment: Re your last question, usually mathematicians are not actually interested in formal logic for some particular first-order theory.  The interest in formal logic is only for _foundational_ theories such as the ZFC in which the semantic argument is formulated.  Then, this foundation is used to reason about other mathematical structures.

Comment: To put it another way, a semantic proof is a perfectly good formal proof in first-order logic--it's just that the underlying theory is ZFC, not T.  And the statement you are proving is $T\vdash F$, not $F$ itself.

Comment: You don't mention that any more than you mention that any other proof was in ZFC.  If you prove a theorem $P$ in algebraic geometry (using $ZFC$ as your foundation), say, you don't say that $ZFC\vdash P$.  You just say that you've proved $P$ (and if someone asks what foundation you're working with, you tell them $ZFC$).  Most of the time, no one really cares what exact foundation you are working with and the default is $ZFC$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that proofs are "easily-recognizable finite strings of symbols" - precisely, we can *effectively enumerate* all proofs from a given theory. So we can always find a formal proof of $F$ from $T$ - if one exists - effectively by simply checking each $T$-proof in order until we find one which is a proof of $F$. This is unsatisfying, but is perfectly precise and effective.

Comment: @V.Semeria If there isn't actually a proof of $F$ from $T$, what do you want your algorithm to do?

Comment: @V.Semeria I still don't understand what you want the *algorithm* to do in this case. Suppose I come to you and present a proof $\pi$, from ZFC + "There is an inaccessible," of ZFC $\vdash p$. But secretly ZFC + "There is an inaccessible" is inconsistent, and in fact ZFC $\not\vdash p$. What do you want your algorithm to do when given $\pi$ (keeping in mind that you don't know at the moment that ZFC + "There is an inaccessible" is inconsistent)?

Comment: On second thought, yes, the risk that this brute force search never terminates perfectly reflects the risk that the stronger theory I used to prove the existence of the formal proof is inconsistent.

Comment: @V.Semeria Or worse, is consistent but wrong *(= consistent but not $\Sigma_1$-sound)* - that way you don't even find out down the road that you were wrong to trust it in the first place!